# Is there any way to add a UIMenu to a UIView?

Tags: swift, uikit, uimenu

I need to add UIMenu (dropdown) to a custom UIView and there is no such option. I have this option on buttons but I really need it on a view.

```
func createMenu() -> UIMenu{
        let destruct = UIAction(title: "Destruct", attributes: .destructive) { _ in }
                
        let items = UIMenu(title: "More", options: .displayInline, children: [
            UIAction(title: "Item 1", image: UIImage(systemName: "mic"), handler: { _ in }),
            UIAction(title: "Item 2", image: UIImage(systemName: "envelope"), handler: { _ in }),
            UIAction(title: "Item 3", image: UIImage(systemName: "flame.fill"), handler: { _ in }),
            UIAction(title: "Item 4", image: UIImage(systemName: "video"), state: .on, handler: { _ in })
        ])
        
        return items
    }
```

The target is iOS 14 so there is no backwards compatibility issue.